# How one can input a small keyboard or any figure in text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How one can input a small keyboard or any figure in text?

Comment: `\includegraphics{keyboard} let x and y be....`

Comment: The `marvosym` package has the `\Keyboard` macro that produces this symbol.

Comment: The [`fontawesome`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome?lang=en) package has `\faKeyboardO` and the [`pifont`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pifont?lang=en) package has `\ding{45}` for the writing hand.